# Someone opened a bank account using my business's EIN -- fraud concern?

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company

I recently formed an LLC and registered it with the IRS to get an EIN. I then went to a bank to set up a business account for the LLC.

The bank ran a check on my LLC's EIN and discovered that, the day after I obtained my EIN from the IRS, someone in a different state had opened an account at a different bank using the same EIN.

It seems most likely that this was a mistake: The other bank may have entered the other business's EIN number incorrectly when setting up their account, with the result that they ended up having an EIN number that matches mine.

Still, I'm wondering if there is any reason to be worried about fraud here, or the possibility that whoever opened the other bank account could somehow claim to be me and take control of my LLC.

Answer (score 5):

There is little risk of *taking control of your business* or similar, but there is a risk that if the other account's owner is unsuccessful, racks up debt, and disappears, the bank's search would turn up your LLC and try to recover his debt.
It might be a good idea to contact that bank and inform that that the other account is not associated with your EIN. If it is a honest error, the owner will dig out his notice and correct the EIN.

Maybe the IRS sent twice the same number out accidentially - it's not like they don't make errors. If that is the outcome, it's also something you should be interested in getting corrected.